# Rails - rendering a javascript file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby & I'm struggling serving a javascript file and executing it.

I'm trying to build an embeddable widget so when someone runs mydomain.com/widget.js, he will get the javascript file which will execute after fetching it

loader.js.erb content:

```
(function(global) {
  var WIDGET = WIDGET || {};

  WIDGET.version = '0.1';
})(this);
```

router.rb content:

```
get 'widget.js' => 'application#test'
```

application_controller.rb content:

```
def test
    render template: 'loader.js.erb', status: :ok,  content_type:'text/javascript'
end
```

I'm expecting after calling for mydomain.com/widget.js, to see WIDGET in the global object, but at the moment it renders it as HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a before filter and make changes in request format:

```
before_filter :set_js_request_format

def set_js_request_format
  request.format = :js
end
```

Hope it is helpful for you.